# MongoDB Aggregation: Extract values from embedded Array And create single array on the root level

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Shape of the document(s) in the collection

```
[
  {
    "predictions": [
      "611b85b9b2b924245526c125"
    ],
    "_id": "611e40b6dd381f18cf63d15f",
   
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "predictions": [
      "611b85b9b2b924245526c125"
    ],
    "_id": "611e40b6dd381f18cf63d160",
    
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

My Aggregation pipeline

```
        ActiveFixture.aggregate([
                {$match:{fixture:{$in:fixtureIds}}},
                {$project:{"predictions":1, _id:0}},
                {$unwind:"$predictions"},
                {$group:{_id:'blah', "Predictions":{"$push":"$predictions"}}}
               
               
                
        ]).exec()
```

Current output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "blah",
    "Predictions": [
      "611b85b9b2b924245526c125",
      "611b85b9b2b924245526c125",
      "611b85b9b2b924245526c125",
      "611b85b9b2b924245526c125"
    ]
  }
]
```

Desired output would be all values from predictions arrays as an single array:

```
["611b85b9b2b924245526c125", "611b85b9b2b924245526c125", "611b85b9b2b924245526c125"]
```

Any ideas, pointers would be much appreciated. Obviously I am well aware it's trivial to transform current output to desired shape  with JS but goal is to achieve final product with MongoDB Aggregation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$unwind` all predictions, group by null(all collection as 1 group), and `$push` all members to array.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3AbAr_tAdF9)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$predictions"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "predictions": {
        "$push": "$predictions"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Wow! I have no idea what just happened but it's actually works

Answer (score 0):

As you want to **skip** your `id column` so you should use the **$skip** command of mongodb.
It allows you to skips **number of documents** or **any other condition as applied by you**

Comment: ```{$skip:"$_id"}```
gives error:
```MongoError: Argument to $skip must be a number not a string```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **conditionally remove** some data from your output. You can use the following **query**

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $project : { "_id" : 0, "predictions" : 1 } } ] )
```

Comment: I have already tried that but result is 

```
[
  {
    "Predictions": [
      "611b85b9b2b924245526c125",
      "611b85b9b2b924245526c125",
      "611b85b9b2b924245526c125",
      "611b85b9b2b924245526c125"
    ]
  }
]

```
Still nested array with unnecessary keys instead of top level array with string items.  I guess this is  best I can get